# Xcode 8 storyboard view controllers all blue background

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8

When I first created my storyboard all the elements on each `UIViewController` showed up just fine; however, after opening up my storyboard again the view controllers have turned all blue.

Is this some kind of issue with Xcode or is there a setting that turns my view controllers blue?

I have checked each subview's `(UIViews, UIImageViews, etc.)` tint color and background color.

[image: Storyboard all blue]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to tap each of them to give them the tabbar icon, then it will become normal

Comment: @butter_baby please mark this as answer so that people know the question is resolved

Comment: Says I have to wait 4 minutes. Patience.

Answer (score 0):

Rashwan [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40248178/xcode-storyboard-is-masking-uitabbarcontroller-elements-with-blue-colour) says that having to add an image, while a good thing, is also a Xcode 8.0 bug that it turns your entire screen blue.

I added an image to the tab bar and it make my screen visible. However, the area where I added an image in the tab bar is now blue and it doesn't display properly when run on the simulator.

I think the solution is to upgrade Xcode past 8.0.