# Xcode storyboard is masking uitabbarcontroller elements with blue colour

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode-storyboard

When I launched my project, all the uitabbarcontroller views are covered in blue. I didn't set the background to blue in code or by using the storyboard. And all of the elements that I add onto the storyboard go behind this mask.

[Here is what it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrtb5.png) What could I be doing wrong?

Using Xcode 10 and Swift 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a **bug** in `Xcode 8`, when you add an image to your `tabbar` item the blue area will be removed for that specific `viewController`. So add an image to the tabbar item and the blue mask will disappear.

Comment: Wow, can not believe how easy that was. Thanks a lot!